# 1 is a regular value of $\det:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to show that 1 is a regular value of $\det:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, *i.e.* that for all $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  the rank of $D(f\circ\phi^{-1})(\phi(A)):\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
 is maximal (and hence equal to 1), where $\phi$
  is a chart on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  at $A$.

I'm guessing I should prove that $D(f\circ\phi^{-1})(\phi(A))$ is surjective, but I don't know how to do this because I don't have an expression for $D(f\circ\phi^{-1})(\phi(A))$. I do know that $\mbox{det}_{*}(I)(X)=\text{tr}(x)$ but I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: User Braindead's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712667/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-n2-1-smooth-submanifold-of-mn-mathbb shows any nonzero number is a regular value of $\det$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the formula we have for computing the determinant by expanding it along any row or column, namely if we expand along the 
$i$-th row we obtain:

$det(X) = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}m_{ij}$

Where $m_{ij}$ is the determinant of the $i,j$-th minor of $X$. We can see that the partial with respect to the $i,j$-th entry will then be $\frac{\partial det}{\partial a_{ij}} = (-1)^{i+j}m_{ij}$. Now all that is left to check is that if the matrix has a nonzero determinant, the jacobian will have rank at least 1. Can you take it from here?

A cool fact, you can use this along with the regular value theorem to prove that $SL_n(\mathbf{R})$ is a Lie subgroup $GL_n(\mathbf{R})$!

Comment: let me try and see if I understood:
The rank of $f=\det$ at $A$  is, by definition, the rank of the linear map $D(f\circ\phi^{-1})(\phi(A)):\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\phi$  is a chart on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$  at $A$. We have $\det_{\bullet}(X):=\det\circ\phi^{-1}(X)=\overset{n}{\underset{j=1}{\sum}}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}m_{ij}$. Now, to $D\det_{\bullet}(\phi(A))$  corresponds the Jacobian $J(\det_{\bullet})|_{\phi(A)}$  whose entries are $\frac{\partial\det_{\bullet}}{\partial a_{ij}}(\phi(A))=(\overset{n}{\underset{j=1}{\sum}}(-1)^{i+j}m_{ij})(\phi(A))$.

Comment: There is something wrong here: $\frac{\partial\det_{\bullet}}{\partial a_{ij}}$
  should be a function of real numbers, not a real number itself...