# diffeomorphism from GL(n,$\Bbb {R}$) to SL($n,\Bbb {R}$) $\times \Bbb{R}^{\times}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

It is Loring W.Tu "An introduction to manifolds" problem 15.9

$f$ has a inverse

$$g: (A, r)\mapsto AM_r$$

but how to show both $f$  and $g$ are $C^\infty$ ?

SL($n,\Bbb R$) have $n^2−1$ coordinates, not its entries

edit：from Chrystomath's answer, I understood that $f$ is $C^\infty$, but I cannot follow his proof about  $g$, I'm just a beginner in manifold

Comment: det is rational in its coordinates, matrix multiplication is polynomial in its entries.

Comment: @Randall   SL(n,R) have $n^2-1$ coordinates, not its entries

Comment: @Clin The proof for $g$ follows as the composition of smooth maps is smooth. Namely, we have that the maps $\varphi: (A,B) \mapsto AB$ and $\psi: r \mapsto M_r$ are smooth and hence $g(A,r) = \varphi(A, \psi(r))$ is smooth too.

Answer (score 3):

$r\mapsto M_r$ is smooth: $$M_{r+h}=M_r+h\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&\cdots\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$$ so the map is differentiable, and the higher derivatives are $0$.

$(A,B)\mapsto AB$ is smooth: $$(A+H)(B+K)=AB+(AK+HB)+HK$$ so the derivative $(H,K)\mapsto AK+HB$ is linear, hence smooth (in finite dimensions).

$A\mapsto \det A$, $GL(n)\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ is multi-linear (from standard theory), hence also smooth.

Trivially, $x\mapsto 1/x$ for $x\ne0$ is smooth, and $A\mapsto(A,A)$ also.

Putting all these together gives that $f,g$ are smooth maps.

Comment: The map $r\mapsto M_r$ is smooth from $Mat(n\times n)$ to itself by your argument (and thus from $GL(n)$ to itself as it is a submanifold). However, $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is not a submanifold of $Mat(n\times n)$, but a quotient. So we need to do an extra step. Also one might remark that the "multilinearity argument" for the regularity of the determinant works as $GL(n)$ is an open subset of $Mat(n\times n)$ (where the argument really works).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712667/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-n2-1-smooth-submanifold-of-mn-mathbb

Comment: @Clin Thanks, I was stupid and thought of $PGL(n)$ instead of $SL(n)$. Still passing to a submanifold is a nontrivial step one should mention.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The intention was not to have a complete proof, but to set OP on track. One also needs to prove injectivity, surjectivity, etc.

Comment: True, I agree that a full proof is not needed (that is why upvoted this answer). Still passing to a submanifold is (for me) a crucial step. That's why I commented.