# Proving that $SU(n)$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, determinant, smooth-manifolds

Considering this post: [Show that $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is a $(n^2 -1)$ smooth submanifold of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712667/show-that-sln-mathbbr-is-a-n2-1-smooth-submanifold-of-mn-mathbb) I dont understand how the manipulations in the limit are done, for instance:

$$ \det(A+tA)=(1+t)^n \det(A)$$

and how the limit overall evaluates to: $n \det(A)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to write out what you have a question about on this post explicitly, but anyway:
$$
\det(A+tA)=\det((1+t)A)=(1+t)^n\det(A)
$$
by the property of determinants of $n\times n$ matrices that says that $\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n \det(A)$. Here we just set $\lambda=1+t$. As for the limit in the post:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\det(A+tA)-\det(A)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^n\det(A)-\det(A)}{t}=\det(A)\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^n-1}{t}$$
$$=\det(A)\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}t^k-1}{t}=\det(A)\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}t^{k-1}=\det(A){n\choose 1}=n\det(A).
$$

Comment: Not L’Hôpital. This is the definition of the derivative. Grr.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. Thanks. :-)